# What is the meaning of "tear to rags"

Tags: idiom-meaning

I am quoting from The Memoirs of Sherlock Holmes, Silver Blaze:

> Holmes shook his head.'A clever counsel would **tear it all to rags**'.

Comment: It is figurative: a good lawyer would destroy the proposed evidence/defence. 'Destroy' in the sense of showing it to be worthless.

Comment: This is figurative language; if you destroy something made of cloth by tearing it to pieces, those pieces are only useful as rags.

Comment: Thank you guys I was confused because I thaught it was a phrasal verb but I still couldn't find it in dictionaries now it is very clear thank you very much

Comment: Hello @aissam! You may be interested in [ell.se]

Answer (score 2):

The question was answered, and the answer was accepted in the comments:

> It is figurative: a good lawyer would destroy the proposed evidence/defence. 'Destroy' in the sense of showing it to be worthless. – Weather Vane Jul 13 at 9:08

> This is figurative language; if you destroy something made of cloth by tearing it to pieces, those pieces are only useful as rags. – Michael Harvey Jul 13 at 9:37

> Thank you guys I was confused because I thaught it was a phrasal verb but I still couldn't find it in dictionaries now it is very clear thank you very much – aissam Jul 13 at 9:53